# Difference between virt-image and virt-clone

Tags: virtualization, xen, linux-kvm

I was reading about virt-manager. However I was really confused between virt-image and virt-clone. Can anyone tell more about it or redirect me to some links that might help me.

My requirement is to build templates so that i can use them for creating new images. I use virt-install for the first installation. Then i do some basic and elementary changes in the template.

Answer (score 0):

In help file of VMware I founded:
"A full clone is a complete and independent copy of a virtual machine. It shares nothing with the parent virtual machine after the cloning operation. Ongoing operation of a full clone is entirely separate from the parent virtual machine."